# how to create a datatable with multiple data listing and sorting in same column?

Tags: datatable, datagrid, datatables-1.10

[Data eable like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amH9n.jpg) 
how can i create a datatable same like the image, same column with two differrent data also need seperate sorting option for each heading.better if it is with data table, any data grid with same feature also better